# uninstall a recently installed app

Tags: software-installation, sudo, cryptocurrency

I installed lnd (lighgning network daemon) using the below command.

```
sudo install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin lnd-linux-armv7-v0.5.1-beta/*
```

What's the cleanest way to remove/rollback this? (I'd like to install a different version). I was thinking of simply removing the binary but would that be enough?

```
rm /usr/local/bin/lnd
```

Comment: I guess it depends on what else was in the directory lnd-linux-armv7-v0.5.1-beta/  You told it to install everything in that directory to /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the tar.gz from the [tutorial I assume you used](https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/raspibolt_40_lnd.md) and there are only two files there `lnd` and `lncli`.

Simply delete these with `sudo rm -f /usr/bin/lnd /usr/bin/lncli`.

Answer (score 0):

[`install`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html) copies the files specified on the command line (in your case, all files inside `lnd-linux-armv7-v0.5.1-beta` to the target directory (in your case, `/usr/local/bin`). In order to undo this, you must find you which files you had in `lnd-linux-armv7-v0.5.1-beta`, and remove files with identical names in the target directory.

If the file names didn't change across two releases, simply installing a newer version in the same directory is enough. `install` overwrites existing files during installation.